# RFC 3339 how make a dateTime from

Tags: php, datetime, google-plus, rfc3339

I'm trying to format a date passed from a google plus Api thats like the guide says in RFC 3339 format:

> PUBLISHED->   datetime->  The time at which this activity was initially published. Formatted as an RFC 3339 timestamp.

So by php documentation i found that:

> DATE_RFC3339
>   Same as DATE_ATOM (since PHP 5.1.3)

And that both format are something like:

> "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP"

Actually the output of the Google api is something like:

> 2014-01-22T10:36:00.222Z

When I'm trying to launch command like:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP", $activity['published']); //$activity['published'] contain the  date
```

I have always `FALSE` as return.
In my opinion the problem is in the final part

> .222Z

any suggestion will be appreciate before cutting it by some rudimental approach...

Comment: Or with standard `date()` method: `date( DATE_RFC3339, $activity['published'] );`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` for standard inputs. Just use:

```php
$date = new DateTime('2014-01-22T10:36:00.222Z');
var_dump($date);
```

But if you still insist to use createFromFormat(), then use correct format, with microseconds:

```php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP', '2014-01-22T10:36:00.222Z');
var_dump($date);
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a trick. A special constant [DATE_RFC3339](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) was made to help, but it does not work if the last character is "Z" -  which is perfectly fine for [rfc3339 format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.8). Actually JSON would specify format like that:

```
expected format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ or YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+hh:mm
```

But using this [DATE_RFC3339](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) you can receive an Error message from PHP:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The timezone could not be found in the database
```

That is why we need to specify format manually:

With DateTime

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat ('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z', $time);
```

With Carbon:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z', $time);
```