# Separate Date and Time from concatenated timestamp variable - PHP

Tags: php, timestamp, string-formatting

I am calling an API.
The format for timestamp returned  is as follows:

```
"Date":"2018-05-06T23:42:03+01:00"
```

How do I separate date from time?

So far, what I have is:

```
$ts = "2018-05-06T23:42:03+01:00";
$date = substr($ts, 0, strpos($ts, "T"));
$date = str_replace($date,"T","");
```

While this would work, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What exact problem are you solving? Given it's a properly formatted RFC3339 why do you want to treat it as strings?

Comment: Yeah - separate them so I can store them in a table - 1 attribute for time another for date - makes my queries faster if I only rely on date.

Comment: You're not following me: why do you treat it as a string while you can treat it as a proper instant? https://3v4l.org/uNGfG

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: [RFC 3339 how make a dateTime from](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383088/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a bad practice to use string functions over a properly formatted RFC3339 datetime.

Instead one would use a datetime parsing functions

```
$dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat(\DateTime::RFC3339, '2018-05-06T23:42:03+01:00');

var_dump($dt->format('H:i:s'));
```

Online demo: https://3v4l.org/uNGfG

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.rfc3339
- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php
- https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt

Answer (score 0):

Split them please

```
$ts = "2018-05-06T23:42:03+01:00";
$splits = explode('T', $ts);
$date = $splits[0]
```